# How to use scipy integrate when a continuous function is multiplied by a discrete function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I would like to use scipy to integrate the following function

[image]

on this function w is a list that is w=linspace(0,10,300). w is experimental data thus why am putting it as a list. I have tried the following code

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

def integrand(t,R):
    return np.exp(R*t)
R=0.04
w=np.linspace(0,10,300)

print(quad(integrand, 0, 4, args=(R)))
```

the problem is that whenever I try to multiply w with the function scipy.integrate is not working. is there a way to overcome this? Am new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot multiply a list by a function. What you probably meant is to interpolate `w` , multiply by the exponential factor and integrate the product. But then you need the values of `t` which correspond to the measured calues of `w`.

Comment: yes, interpolating looks good. Let me try learning some interpolation method so that I can find the continuous function representative of the data and multiply the function. Thanks